# How do you delete sublists of a desired permutation?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list given as:

```
d = {{{A1,A2,T3}, {A4,T1,A2}, {T5,A1,A3}}, {{T1,T2,T3}, {A5,A1,A2},{A1,A2,T3}}}
```

I'm trying to delete sublists of the type:

```
{A,A,A},{A,T,T},{T,T,T}
```

that way I'm left with sublists consisting of only:

```
{A,A,T},{T,A,A},{A,T,A}
```

I'm also trying to keep the numbers in list "d" so my desired outcome would look something like:

```
dd={{{A1,A2,T3},{A4,T1,A2}, {T5,A1,A3}},{{A1,A2,T3}}}
```

I have tried the following:

`DeleteCases[d,{A,A,A}|{T,T,T}|{A,T,T},{2}]` but nothing seems to change.  I think there's an issue with my patterns in DeleteCases where I need to include additional information to exclude the numbers in list "d" and just delete the sublists based upon the criteria of the arrangement of the A's and T's.

Edit: Originally this question was posted with list "d" as a list of symbol, when it should have in fact been a list of strings.  I have since rectified that issue by keeping the original question and adding my intended question below, that way answers already provided could be insight for people looking for the same thing.

I have a list given as:

```
d = {{{"A1","A2","T3"}, {"A4","T1","A2"}, {"T5","A1","A3"}}, {{"T1","T2","T3"}, {"A5","A1","A2"},{"A1","A2","T3"}}}
```

I'm trying to delete sublists of the type:

```
{"A","A","A"},{"A","T","T"},{"T","T","T"}
```

that way I'm left with sublists consisting of only:

```
{"A","A","T"},{"T","A","A"},{"A","T","A"}
```

I'm also trying to keep the numbers in list "d" so my desired outcome would look something like:

```
dd={{{"A1","A2","T3"},{"A4","T1","A2"}, {"T5","A1","A3"}},{{"A1","A2","T3"}}}
```

I have tried the following:

`DeleteCases[d,{A,A,A}|{T,T,T}|{A,T,T},{2}]` but nothing seems to change.  I think there's an issue with my patterns in DeleteCases where I need to include additional information to exclude the numbers in list "d" and just delete the sublists based upon the criteria of the arrangement of the A's and T's.

Comment: If you think that you are going to do a lot of this kind of processing, I'd recommend that you consider switching to indexed variables instead, i.e. something like `{{{a[1], a[2], t[3]}, ...`. It would make the pattern matching much easier. See my answer below for a method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
undesirable = {{A, A, A}, {A, T, T}, {T, T, T}};
DeleteCases[d,
 {x_, y_, z_} /; 
   MemberQ[undesirable, 
    Symbol@StringTake[SymbolName[#], 1] & /@ {x, y, z}
   ],
 {2}
]

(* Out: {{{A1, A2, T3}, {A4, T1, A2}, {T5, A1, A3}}, {{A1, A2, T3}}} *)
```

---

If you think that you are going to do a lot of this kind of processing, I'd recommend that you consider switching to indexed variables instead, i.e. something like {{{a[1], a[2], t[3]}, .... It would make the pattern matching much easier.

Here is a function that generates a set of rules to change your expressions into this new format:

```
varChangeRules =
  Function[{list},
   Symbol[#1 ~~ #2] -> Symbol[ToLowerCase@#1][ToExpression@#2] & @@@ 
    Characters@*SymbolName /@ Variables[list]
  ];

newd = d /. varChange[d]

(* Out: {{{a[1], a[2], t[3]}, {a[4], t[1], a[2]}, {t[5], a[1], a[3]}}, 
         {{t[1], t[2], t[3]}, {a[5], a[1], a[2]}, {a[1], a[2], t[3]}}} *)
```

The elimination of your unwanted sequences is then easier:

```
DeleteCases[
  newd, 
  {Repeated[_a, 3]} | {Repeated[_t, 3]} | {_a, _t, _t}, 
  All
]

(* Out: {{{a[1], a[2], t[3]}, {a[4], t[1], a[2]}, {t[5], a[1], a[3]}}, 
         {{a[1], a[2], t[3]}}} *)
```

Comment: That is an interesting way of doing it, especially if I continue down the path I'm going I think this could be useful.  Would the code still work if instead of the "d" I have list above, it was this instead?  d = {{{"A1","A2","T3"}, {"A4","T1","A2"}, {"T5","A1","A3"}}, {{"T1","T2","T3"}, {"A5","A1","A2"},{"A1","A2","T3"}}}

Comment: @D'Angelo No, that would require a change in the code. But actually it would be easier to work with. Now, which one do you actually use, the list of strings, or the list of symbols? Because you posted a list of symbols in the OP, which was actually bad news. The strings are possibly easier to deal with, but require a completely different approach. So before I go down another rabbit hole, which one do you actually have? :-)

Comment: Really sorry about that, I actually happen to have a list of strings, I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience.  What you had posted though was definitely useful because I have list of symbols in my code in which your posted approach proved to be quite insightful.

Answer (score 2):

```
delQ = MatchQ[{A, A, A} | {A, T, T} | {T, T, T}] @*
    Map[Symbol @* First @* Characters @* ToString];

DeleteCases[d, _?delQ, {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{{A1, A2, T3}, {A4, T1, A2}, {T5, A1, A3}}, {{A1, A2, T3}}}
> ```

```
delQ2 = StringMatchQ["AAA" | "ATT" | "TTT"] @* 
   StringJoin @* Map[StringTake[#, 1] & @* SymbolName];

DeleteCases[d, _?delQ2, {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{{A1, A2, T3}, {A4, T1, A2}, {T5, A1, A3}}, {{A1, A2, T3}}}
> ```

**Update:** If the the input list is a nested list of strings as in

```
d2 = Map[ToString, d, {-1}]
```

> ```
>  {{{"A1", "A2", "T3"}, {"A4", "T1", "A2"}, {"T5", "A1", "A3"}},
>  {{"T1", "T2", "T3"}, {"A5", "A1", "A2"}, {"A1", "A2", "T3"}}}
> ```

you can use

```
sdelQ = StringMatchQ["AAA"|"ATT"|"TTT"] @* StringJoin @* Map[StringTake[#, 1] &];

DeleteCases[d2, _?sdelQ, {2}]
```

> ```
>  {{{"A1", "A2", "T3"}, {"A4", "T1", "A2"}, {"T5", "A1", "A3"}},
>   {{"A1", "A2", "T3"}}}
> ```

Comment: Would this code change if my list "d" was represented like this?d = {{{"A1","A2","T3"}, {"A4","T1","A2"}, {"T5","A1","A3"}}, {{"T1","T2","T3"}, {"A5","A1","A2"},{"A1","A2","T3"}}}

Comment: @D'Angelo, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 
 {{{A1, A2, T3}, {A4, T1, A2}, {T5, A1, A3}}, {{T1, T2, T3}, 
  {A5, A1, A2}, {A1, A2, T3}}};

x = {{A, A, A}, {A, T, T}, {T, T, T}};

Delete[
 d,
 Position[
  Map[StringTake[#, 1]& @* ToString, d, {3}],
  Alternatives @@ Map[ToString, x, {2}]
  ]]
```

{{{A1, A2, T3}, {A4, T1, A2}, {T5, A1, A3}}, {{A1, A2, T3}}}